# VBA check sheet for filtered data

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any way to check if sheets have any filtered data (If there is filtered data, then clear filter, else do nothing)? I have this code here, but I don't know how to write second part:

```
Sub ProtectAll()

Dim wSheet          As Worksheet

For Each wSheet In Worksheets

With wSheet
If .AutoFilterMode Then
            .ShowAllData
            .Cells.Locked = True
            .Cells.FormulaHidden = False
           '.Range(wSheet.Cells(12, 1), wSheet.Cells(12, 18)).AutoFilter
           '.Protect Password:=Pwd, AllowFiltering:=True

ElseIf ??? Then
End If
End With

Next wSheet
End Sub
```

Comment: Refer to excel help [Google excel autofilter](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=msdn+excel+autofilter+property) and [MSDN excel autofilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834384.aspx)

Comment: @d-stroyer Thanks for suggestion. I found out that reapplying filter does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This code removes all autofilters from ActiveSheet

```
ActiveSheet.Autofilter.Range.Autofilter
```

Afterwards you can reset the filter (no criteria selected) by defining an appropriate range

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B1").Autofilter
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is using .FilterMode

```
If Sheets("NameSheet").FilterMode Then Sheets("NameSheet").ShowAllData
```

This code removes filtered data the sheet have and show all data keeping autofilters.